# Converting a single string to Array results in {"Non-static method requires a target."}

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, string

I am converting a single string into a string[] but I can getting the {"Non-static method requires a target."} error message.  I did a search on the web and there is many cases that people have received that error but non seem to be in line with the situation I have.

Here is the code that I receive the error at:

```
string[] techEmail = { db.Users.Single(u => u.NTUserName.Equals(ticket.Technician.NTUserName)).EmailAddress.ToString() };
```

I even tried without the .ToString() and also tried to use this method:

```
string[] result = " [null,null,'3',null,null,null]".Replace("[","").Replace("]","").Split(',');
```

Here is the second attempt using the code above:

```
string[] techEmail = " [" + db.Users.Single(u => u.NTUserName.Equals(ticket.Technician.NTUserName)).EmailAddress.ToString() + "]".Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Split(',');
```

but nothing worked.  This seems like something that should be so simple.

Comment: Your second code block should work fine. Are you saying `result.Length` is zero ?

Comment: This doesn't look like it would result in that particular error message.  How have you confirmed that this is the exact code causing the problem?  Can you break this apart into multiple statements to narrow down more specifically which operation is causing the error?

Comment: Side-Note: instead of your replace-approach you should use `Trim('[',']',' ')`. Also, what is`EmailAddress` at all? This doesn't look like one: `[null,null,'3',null,null,null]`

Comment: @David two reasons I believe that is the code that is causing the crash.  1) When the debugger opens that is the line of code that it is stopping on 2) I had all the code working and this is the only line I have changed (for a different reason)

Comment: This error normaly ocourrs when you have a class `Foo` with a function `bar()`and you try to call it like that: `Foo.bar();` This won't work. You have to create an instance first: `Foo f = new  Foo(); f.bar();` So check your types. Maybe there is an error.

Comment: @Sammy, if I run the db.users... code that is in the middle by itself then it works, so I don't think it has anything to do with that.  I may be wrong though.

Comment: try this "var check = db.Users.Single(u => u.NTUserName.Equals(ticket.Technician.NTUserName)).EmailAddress;". It will probably gave error too. So your string[] is not the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use List and add your string to it later.
Something like that:

```
string email = db.Users.Single(u => u.NTUserName.Equals(ticket.Technician.NTUserName)).EmailAddress.ToString();
List<string> techEmail = new List<string>();
techEmail.Add(email);
```